# ##[error]Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden' error Azure pipeline running Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have got a pipeline running in Azure, it runs the Azure powershell task with the following commands below. Now, I have tested this on my powershell console and it works perfectly well.On the face of it, it looks like a permission issue, however what puzzles me is that the database creation works, what doesn't work is the section where it runs the below.

`$database | Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -DisplayName "xxxxx"`

The full inline script

```
    $my_rg = "xxxx"
    $my_db = "xxx"
    $my_server = "xxx"
    
    $database = New-AzSqlDatabase  -ResourceGroupName $my_rg `
        -ServerName $my_server `
        -DatabaseName $my_db `
        -RequestedServiceObjectiveName "S1" `
        -Edition "Standard"

$database | Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -DisplayName "xxxxx"
```

The pipeline throws the error.

```
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\17384b06-bf34-4f38-a0b3-8ade4268c4e6.ps1'"
Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\az_3.1.0\Az.Accounts\2.2.5\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
WARNING: Both Az and AzureRM modules were detected on this machine. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the 
same session or used in the same script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can
 use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove all AzureRm modules from your machine. If you are running in Azure 
Automation, take care that none of your runbooks import both Az and AzureRM modules. More information can be found 
here: https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide
Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant xxxxxxx -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
 Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId xxxx -TenantId xxxxxxxxxxx
##[error]Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

Answer (score 1):

> ##[error]Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

Based on the error message, the cause of the issue is that the service connection has no access to set the Administrator of the Azure SQL server.

In Azure DevOps, the service connection will create a service principal in Azure Portal and then it will use the service principal's permissions to access Azure resource.

To solve this issue, you can grant the Azure SQL server **Owner** Role to the service principal.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Check the service principal in **Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations**.

Step2: Grant the service principal  **Owner** Role  in **Azure SQL Server -> Access control**